# Separar datos de una misma celda en Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en VisualBasic for Applications (VBA), dentro de Excel.

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente código, busco saber como podría hacer para separar datos que están dentro de una misma celda.
Mi objetivo es separarlos por un delimitador, el cual sería "-" (Guión).

```
Dim WrdArray() As String

Dim expresion As String

expresion = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Select
'expresion = ActiveSheet.Range(C5:C38).Select

WrdArray() = Split(expresion, "-")

'For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)

strg = strg & vbNewLine & " - " & WrdArray(i)

'Next i

MsgBox strg

End Sub
```

Con este código, el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente

[image: Resultado actual]

A continuación dejo una imagen de apoyo.

[image: Datos a separar]

Es decir, que con esta macro sea posible dividir los datos tomando en cuenta el guión intermedio.

Que 1081 lo ponga en una celda y 1091 en otra

Espero sea posible obtener su ayuda

Muchas gracias, buen día

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes beneficiarte de la instrucción Split:

> **[Función Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Long

i = 1
Do Until Range("A" & i).Value = ""
    Range("B" & i).Value = Split(Range("A" & i).Value, " - ")(1)
    Range("A" & i).Value = Split(Range("A" & i).Value, " - ")(0)
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para esto tienes varias opciones. La más sencilla es utilizar la grabadora de macros y la opción "Texto en columnas" que te permite separar en columnas utilizando un delimitador, en tu caso el guión.

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Otra opción podría ser recorrer tu columna de datos, localizar el guion y pasar a un array (n,1) los valores para pegar esos datos en la hoja al finalizar. Si la cadena de valores es siempre de la misma longitud es muy sencillo separar los valores con las funciones right y left.

Un ejemplo sencillo suponiendo que tus datos están en la columna A:

```
Sub Ejemplo()

    ReDim arrDatos(15, 1)
    x = 0
    For i = 1 To 15
    
        arrDatos(x, 0) = Left(Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A" & i), 4)
        arrDatos(x, 1) = Right(Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A" & i), 4)
        x = x + 1
    
    Next

    Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B1:C15") = arrDatos

End Sub
```

Saludos.